# Powershell command copies files with certain name and paste in a folder with the name same as current date

Tags: powershell

I am using following code to create a folder with current date name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
$Path = 'C:\temp'
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("ddMMyyyy")
New-Item -itemType Directory -Path $Path -Name $FolderName
```

After this code, I want to add another code that copies files from certain directory and puts them into this newly created folder with current date name.
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't error out with your first `Get-Childitem`? There's nothing assigned to the variable unless you left that part out. And you can use `copy-item` to help you copy. Run `help Copy-Item` to get the full syntax of the command. Irs usually just used by providing the source, then destination. `Copy-Item c:\path1 -Destination C:\path2`

Comment: No error, it just creates a folder with the name same as current date.
Actually I want to set -Destination to search for a folder with certain name, in this case the folder with name as current that just got created with above code. Do you have any idea how to give this command?

Comment: Hello, did you look at the help for `copy-item`? `Copy-Item -Path C:\my\other\directory -Destination $Path\$folderName`

Comment: Yes I had a look at help for copy-item but could not get around it as I am newbie. This works! Thanks alot.

Comment: PowerShell parses code from top to bottom, so you should move the line `$Path = 'C:\temp'` on top of the code, so the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet knows where to look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
  cp C:\temp\filename.txt "$path\$foldername\"
```

Comment: Please upvote and click the 'accept answer' tick if it's helpful - That means a lot to me :)